# Model theory/topology/type theory

Tags: general-topology, model-theory

I am given two stone spaces $S_n$ and $S'_n$ for some n. 
A stone space in model theory context is a space where the elements are complete types taking n inputs (i.e. if $\phi(x) \in p$ is a complete type, $p\in S_1$.)

I'm told L is the language of $S_n$ and $L\subseteq L'$ and $T \subseteq T'$, L' is the language of $S'_n$, T, T' complete.

I'm asked to prove a function $f: S'_n \rightarrow S_n$, $f(p) = p \cap \{L formulas\}$ is continuous. Continuous in the sense that for every open set V of $S_n$,  $f^{-1}(V)$ is also open.

My problem is that I don't understand how this function can possibly be 1-1. This is essentially all I need to prove continuity, but why is it 1-1? I've spun this around in my head so many times.

Why can't there be complete types p, q of $S'_n$ such that there is a complete type r of $S_n$ where $r\subseteq p, q$?

Comment: It is generally not 1-1. For example, take $L$ to be the empty language (i.e. just equality) and take $L'$ to have one unary relation symbol $R$. Then $S_1$ had only one point while $S_1'$ has two points (distinguishes by $R(x)$ and $\neg R(x)$). (all of this is modulo the theory of infinite sets)

Comment: Here is a start: what are the (basic) open sets of each space?

Comment: @MarkKamsma It would be the sets U_phi, phi a formula (in each language). I don't see how this can give me a basic open set. Take, for example, an isolated complete type p in Sn. Then {p} is basic, but is it necessarily the case that f^-1(p) is basic?I guess because it gives all the types in which p is a subset? Then this has to be open and basic because no other open sets can make it with union, and the open sets must cover S'n?

Comment: Well, if $\{p\}$ happens to be open, it is still of the form $U_\phi$ for some formula $\phi$. That last bit is all you need to focus on: what is $f^{-1}(U_\phi)$? Also, remember that it is enough for continuity to check that the preimage of every basic open is open.

Comment: What makes you think the function should be one-to-one? Being one-to-one is completely independent from being continuous. I'm going out on a limb here, but maybe you think $f^{-1}$ is notation for the inverse function, and only one-to-one function have (partially defined) inverses? It's not: $f^{-1}(V)$ in this case is notation for the preimage set, $f^{-1}(V) = \{p\in S_n'\mid f(p)\in V\}$.

Comment: I would think a stone space is space where you store stones  @Cantorexample (But, perhaps the Saturn rings qualify too.)

Comment: By the way, the meaning of "type" in type theory is totally unrelated to the meaning of "type" in model theory. I removed the (type-theory) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic open set in $S_n$ has the form $[\varphi] = \{p\in S_n\mid \varphi\in p\}$, for some $L$-formula $\varphi$ in $n$ free variables. Then:
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}([\varphi]) &= \{p\in S'_n\mid f(p)\in [\varphi]\}\\
&= \{p\in S'_n\mid \varphi\in f(p)\}\\
&= \{p\in S'_n\mid \varphi\in p\}
\end{align*}

The last step is because restricting $p$ to $L$ does not affect whether the $L$-formula $\varphi$ is in $p$. The last set is exactly $[\varphi]$ in the space $S'_n$, which is again a basic open set. We have checked that the preimage of every basic open set is open, so $f$ is continuous.

> My problem is that I don't understand how this function can possibly be 1-1. This is essentially all I need to prove continuity, but why is it 1-1?

As Mark Kamsma pointed out in the comments, a restriction map $f$ is usually not one-to-one. But as I pointed out in the comments, being one-to-one has nothing at all to do with continuity.